# Entanglement entropy with a local operator insertion

Tags: quantum-entanglement, conformal-field-theory, causality, ads-cft

According to several papers discussing the behavior of entanglement entropy (EE) with a local quench or a local operator insertion (cf. https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.04797), if the operator was inserted far away from the subregion, it does not instantly affect to the reduced density matrix and hence EE is same as the vacuum EE. (This is the statement.)

I think this is due to causality; the domain of dependence of the subregion does not contain the point of the operator insertion before some sufficient time.

However, I think this explanation is  puzzling since EE of any pure state should equal to EE of the complement and the domain of dependence of the complement region should include the point of the operator insertion. Furthermore, in case the local operator is not unitary, I think the reduced density matrix cannot equal to the one without the operator excitation. (This is my question.)

Is there any simple, intuitive explanation for this seemingly contradicting statement?

Comment: But the state after the operator insertion will not be pure, generically, as they account for in the paper, by describing it by a density matrix. Furthermore, given a reduced density matrix on a subset A, there is no unique state on all of the system producing it; it can be obtained from pure, and from mixed states.

Comment: Well for example in this paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1405.5946.pdf, the state after the operator insertion is given by O(x)|0> if one take t=0 and \epsilon\rightarrow 0 limit. This is a pure state. But even if i’m that situation the difference from the EE of vacuum is zero and is it true? In your latter statement, you are saying the same reduced density matrix can be produced from different states? Yes, I understand this point. Though, unless the inserted operator is unitary, such a case seems special for me.

Comment: Maybe my confusion was resolved by thinking as follows: By acting an local operator on a site of some spin chain, the site, for example |0>, turns into |O(x)>. But this is just a local basis change and hence it can be realized as a local unitary operator. Thus unless the effect of the insertion is smeared by some time evolution by a nonlocal Hamiltonian, there is nothing different from the vacuum as long as you focus on EE. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: You are right, the resulting state is of course pure. I don't think it wise to restrict to unitary O(x) though, and the authors of the paper you have cited do not restrict in that way. In the case of general, not necessarily unitary O, one has to renormalize the state after the quench.

Comment: I think the problem may be resolved by stating that there is no contradiction entailed by the state being pure after the quench, and that the entanglement entropy of subsystem A is equal to the entanglement entropy of its complement. It is true that the insertion is contained in the complement, but the entanglement entropy only starts being affected when the influence of the operator reaches the boundary of the subsystem - since the entanglement entropy measures entanglement across that boundary.

Comment: As an (non-CFT) example of many states having the same reduced density matrix: Consider the ground state of a local (gapped, for simplicity) Hamiltonian, and assume there are particle-like excitations in the spectrum. Then an example for such a quench would be the insertion of a number of these particles into the system, an operation which is not unitary. Anyhow, the particles being localized, the reduced density matrix of any subregion sufficiently far away will be the one of the ground state for some time, until the effect of the insertions can propagate to that region.

Comment: I' not sure I understand: Is the question why the entanglement between two regions A and B does not change if I act with a (physical, deterministic) operator on some sites in region A?

Comment: @LorenzMayer If O is not unitary, it will generally change the entanglement.